# C# generic implicit operator return type

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

For purposes of automatically translating code from C++ to C#, I would like to have a C# class (psuedo-code)

```
class Null {
    public static implicit operator T (Null unused) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This would be useful in cases such as

```
foo(T1 x) { ... }
foo(T2 x) { ... }

foo(null); // ambiguous
```

For certain reasons, programmatically disambiguating the above type is not in general possible. E.g.

```
foo((T1)null); // Discovering T1 over T2 is not possible or really hard to do
```

But if I had the `Null` class above, I could programmatically add in

```
foo(Null x) {...}
```

and generate

```
foo(new Null()); // not ambiguous
```

The trick would be to use `new Null()` in place of every generated `null` such that even

```
T1 x = new Null();
```

compiles with `x == null`.

Is it possible to write such a class?

Comment: That is crude. Why don't you just use `foo() {...}`? If i understand you correctly: If you encounter `foo(null);` in your C++ code, you need to introduce the method `foo(Null x) {...}` in C# and call it accordingly instead of foo(null). How would this be different from: If you encounter `foo(null);` in your C++ code, you need to introduce the method `foo() {...}` in C# and call it accordingly instead of foo(null). (Of courser, there could always be a foo() method in C++, as there could be also already a NULL type declaration in C++.)

Comment: @elgonzo: Crudeness doesn't matter to me. Yes, I could do something similar (add in `foo(UniqueToken)` because `foo()` may already exist), but I would want to avoid that because it would require much more work to implement if writing the `Null` class is possible.

Comment: I extended just my original comment. If it matters whether foo() could exist, then it should also matter that also a C++ type declaration for Null could exist and be used as parameter for foo(Null x) in C++. In both cases you would need to vary the conflicting names (for example foo1() or Null1 in C#) -- I still don't see a major benefit of your approach

Comment: @elgonzo: It's not that simple. For example, translating C++ `foo(size_t count, T * arr)` has to translate to `foo(T[] arr)`. If there was also a `foo(T x)` (more or less... it's a little simplified), that goes to `foo(T)`. Here if the original code was `foo(0, nullptr)` it gets to `foo(null)` in C#. I can overcome this in my translator, but it requires more work than I would like. In any case, I think the above question is interesting in its own right even if one cannot see a practical use for it.

Comment: Ah, i understand now. It looked to me that `foo(null)` was related to an equivalent C++ function call, but i understand now that you encounter `foo(null)` on the C# side as a result of some C++ code transformation... hmm...

Comment: What does the `foo(T1)` does, `foo(T2)`? What is the behaviour of `foo(null)`? Which overload of `foo` was usually called in C++? You say you don't want to use conversion operators, but when you call `foo` you and compiler have to **know** which overload should be called. So what is the problem with explicit casts? Does it really save a lot of work? I doubt. If there is some scenario where such solution is necessary then demonstrate it, otherwise it will just clutter your program and reduce **explicitness** of your code - `foo()` is more descriptive and direct method then `foo(Null nullObj)`.

Comment: For one, the generated code is already an unholy mess, but since it is generated code, I could care less. Also, forget about the fact that this question may be an X-Y problem. I'm still interested if such a class is possible to write even if it is not the "correct" solution.

Comment: One question: `foo(0, nullptr)` would be a call of the C++ function `foo(size_t count, T * arr)` and `foo(nullptr)` would be call of the `foo(T)` function, right? If both C++ constructs `foo(0, nullptr)` and `foo(nullptr)` transform into the same C# construct `foo(new Null())`, then you already have lost the information regarding which actual foo(...) function should be called. Perhaps turn the *Null* type into a generic type *Null<T>*, which would make `foo(0, nullptr)` translate into `foo(new Null<T[]>())` and `foo(nullptr)` into `foo(new Null<T>())`. Would this be a possibility?

Comment: However, if it would be possible for you to create C# constructs like `foo(new Null<T[]>())` or `foo(new Null<T>())`, then you would also be able to construct `foo((T[])null)` and `foo((T)null)` very easily. If that is not possible because you don't have the argument type information anymore, then also a magical Null class will not help you pulling the missing type information out of nothing...

Comment: @ThomasEding: If you have `foo<T>(T x)` and `foo<T>(T[] arr)`, then you can simply add a `foo(object o)`, and then calls to `foo(null)` will resolve to that overload. But you never answered Eugene's question--how do you know what the correct behavior for `foo(null)` is? Is it supposed to behave like `foo(T)` or like `foo(T[])`, or neither, or sometimes one and sometimes the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Absent the `dynamic` keyword, all method binding in C# is done at compile-time--even binding to implicit cast operators. That means that the problem you're running into with method overload resolution will also prevent the compiler from being able to figure out whether you want your `null` to be implicitly cast to a T1 or a T2. And using `dynamic` won't work, because `null` doesn't have any type at runtime.

It is possible that there are other solutions to your problem if you can share more information. For example, if either of the two methods would work correctly when passed a null value, and you're just trying to get the generated code to compile, you could create a method like this:

```
foo(object o) {return Foo((T1)null);}
```

And then translate calls to:

```
foo(new object());
```

The above method would also work if you wanted to use a `Null` class instead of `object`--no implicit cast is necessary.

On the other hand, if it *does* matter which overload gets called with a null value, then you need to tell us how the original program determines which one to call.